# Angular 2 observable subscribing twice executes call twice

Tags: angular, subscribe

**Problem**
I subscribe to an httpClient.get observable twice. However, this means that my call gets executed twice. Why is this?

**Proof**
For every subscribe() I do, I get another line in the login page.

**Code (onSubmit() from login page button)**

```
var httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
  .append("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa(this.username + ':' + this.password));

var observable = this.httpClient.get('api/version/secured', { headers: httpHeaders});
observable.subscribe(
  () => {
    console.log('First request completed');
  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log('First request error');
  }
);
observable.subscribe(
  () => {
    console.log('Second request completed');
  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log('Second request error');
  }
);
```

**Console**

```
zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:4200/api/version/secured 401 (Unauthorized)
login.component.ts:54 First request error
zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:4200/api/version/secured 401 (Unauthorized)
login.component.ts:62 First request error
```

**Irrelevant background**
I have a LogonService object which handles al my login functionality. It contains a boolean variable that shows whether I am logged in or not. Whenever I call the login function, it subscribes to the observable of the httpClient.get, to set the login variable to true or false. But the login function also returns the observable, which gets subscribed to. Took me some time to link the double request to the double subscription. If there is a better way of tracking the login than through a variable, let me know! I am trying to learn angular :)

Comment: That's how normal observables work. You need to use a subject if you want many subcribers to be notified when the code is executed once http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You may use the [`share`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) operator on your result from `HttpClient.get`, like this:

```
var observable = this.httpClient.get('api/version/secured', { headers: httpHeaders })
  .pipe(share());
```

You'll need to add the following import on top of your script:

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The `share` operator makes an observable `hot`, i.e. shared between subscribers. But there's a lot more to it, I would suggest [this article](https://alligator.io/rxjs/hot-cold-observables/) to dive deeper (you can of course also google up `hot vs cold observables` to find more).

Comment: Fixed my problem, thnx!

Answer (score 9):

Your observable is cold:

> An observable is cold if the producer of its notifications is created
>   whenever an observer subscribes to the observable. For example, a
>   timer observable is cold; each time a subscription is made, a new
>   timer is created.

You need to `multicast` your Observable, or in other words, to make it hot:

> An observable is hot if the producer of its notifications is not
>   created each time an observer subscribes to the observable. For
>   example, an observable created using fromEvent is hot; the element
>   that produces the events exists in the DOM — it’s not created when the
>   observer is subscribed.

For this you can use [share](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) operator, but it still cannot guarantee you a single http call. Share will `multicast` your observable, making it shared between the subscribers, but once the http call completes it will make a new http call for new subscribers.

If you want a caching behavior (performing the call once and then providing the value to each subscriber whenever it subscribes) you should use `publishReplay().refCount()`.

### Further reading:

[Publish and share operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the caching behavior. That was actually something I was asking myself, but wanted to do more research for asking it here!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, you can assign to observable your `http` service and then subscribe to the get data. For example:

```
export class App implements OnInit {

lessons$: Observable<Lessons[]>;

constructor(private lessonsService: lessonsService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.lessons$ = this.lessonsService.loadLessons().publishLast().refCount();

    this.lessons$.subscribe(
         () => console.log('lessons loaded'),
         console.error
         );
    }
}
```

[The Angular documentation.](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-rxjs-common-pitfalls/)

Answer (score -2):

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

> **Invokes an execution** of an Observable and registers Observer handlers 
>   for notifications it will emit.